# C# regular expression to strip all but alphabetical and numerical characters from a string?

Tags: c#, regex

I've been scratching my head trying to figure out how to use Regex.Replace to take an arbitrary string and return a string that consists of only the alpha-numeric characters of the original string (all white space and punctuation removed).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use linq:

```
string alphanumeric = new String(original.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray());
```